# How can i make this loop faster

Tags: autoit

theres is some way to make this loop faster in autoit

```
#include <AutoItConstants.au3>

Local $i = 0
Do

Opt("MouseClickDelay", 0)
MouseClick ( "left",1133,583,1,0)

Opt("MouseClickDelay", 0)
MouseClick ( "left",1120,204,1,0)
$i = $i + 1
Until $i = 100000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Opt("MouseClickDelay", 0)
Opt("MouseClickDownDelay", 1)

For $i = 0 To 100000
    MouseClick("left", 1133, 583, 1, 0)
    MouseClick("left", 1120, 204, 1, 0)
Next
```